# How do I return a value extracted by a "combined keyword" in GoTest?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I created a combined keyword in GoTest to run a bit of script to extract the index of a component on a web page. I want to use that as a locator in my Selenium test.
GoTest is a wrapper UI around RobotFramework.

I tried to create a global variable and put the value in that global variable, but it doesn't seem to work. The variable is empty when I try to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the result calculated by your combined keyword script into a variable and then put that variable in the return field of the combined keyword.

Example of the result:

[image: image exemple of the result]

Comment: thank you @lemon for the hint/review :)